# sum( case when ... end ) group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select sum(case when(remark='Regular') then count(*)
               when(remark='Half Day') then count(*)* 0.5
           end),
       shift
from attendance
where empid='1447' and mont='02' and payyear='2015'
group by shift, remark
order by shift
```

How to write in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Put the case inside the aggregation function:

```
select sum(case when remark = 'Regular' then 1
                when remark = 'Half Day' then 0.5
           end),
       shift
from attendance
where empid='1447' and mont='02' and payyear='2015'
group by shift
order by shift
```

Also, remove `remark` from the `group by`.